# How to set VIM's background based on terminal's background colour?

Tags: vimrc

I use CentOS 7 which has VIM 7.4 installed. By default the `background` property of VIM here is set to `light` irrespective of the colourscheme of my terminal. Although I can always force the desired `background` property in my `vimrc`, I do not want this.

In Ubuntu (18.04 which has VIM 8), `background` property automatically changes between `light` and `dark` based on the colourscheme of my terminal. This is true even when I am ssh-ing to the Ubuntu machine from my CentOS machine.

Therefore, I would like to know whether the ability of VIM changing `background` property automatically is specific to newer versions. And if this is not true, then how do I achieve the same effect in CentOS?

Comment: In CentOS, `term=xterm-256color`; `$COLORFBGB` is not set; third command gives `E121: Undefined variable: v:termrbgresp` and `E15: Invalid expression: v:termrbgresp`; and last command gives `E846: Key code not set: t_RB`.

Comment: In Ubuntu, `term=xterm-256color`; `$COLORFGBG` is not set; third command gives `^[]11;rgb:3232/3030/2f2f^G`; and output of last command is `t_RB=^[]11;?^G`.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has a few mechanisms for detecting the background colour of your terminal, which are described in `:help 'background'`:

> When the |t_RB| option is set, Vim will use it to request the background
>       color from the terminal.  If the returned RGB value is dark/light and
>       'background' is not dark/light, 'background' will be set and the
>       screen is redrawn.  This may have side effects, make t_BG empty in
>       your .vimrc if you suspect this problem.  The response to |t_RB| can
>       be found in |v:termrbgresp|.
>
> [...]
>
> For MS-DOS, Windows and OS/2 the default is "dark".
>       For other systems "dark" is used when 'term' is "linux",
>       "screen.linux", "cygwin" or "putty", or $COLORFGBG suggests a dark
>       background.  Otherwise the default is "light".

By looking at the repository history, it seems as though the mechanism using a terminal query/response was first added in version 7.4.757 in 2015, although it looks as though it was still being tweaked as late as version 8.0.1129, in 2017.

If your version of Vim is older than that, then you should be able to get Vim to detect the background by setting an appropriate value of `COLORFGBG` in your shell. (e.g. `7;0`. The first number is the foreground, the second is the background. Vim sets `'background'` to `dark` if the second value is `0-6` or `8`.) This variable is automatically set by some shells, and it looks like Vim has been using it for background-detection since around 2011.

More details on how Vim (and other apps) detect background colours can be found in the answers to [this question on the Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245378/63001).

Comment: Thank you. It seems that CentOS 7 has vim 7.4 (2013) version. In this `t_RB` setting is not available. Additionally, as you said , settings `COLORFGBG` seems to work, i.e., vim then automatically sets the `background` property. But that does not solves the problem. I now have to set `COLORFGBG` environment variable instead of setting `background` value in vimrc. Either way, the effort seems to be the same when I intend to change the terminal colour scheme.

Comment: .vimrc example possible for new vim users? The "classic" .vimrc that I found do not contain a t_RB... Thx

Comment: @GGleGrand If your terminal is configured correctly, `t_RB` will be set up automatically on Vim startup: you don't need to add it to your `.vimrc`.