# updating running neovim's setting `background` using a terminal response

Tags: neovim, terminal

On my laptop, I frequently swap between a dark and a bright colorscheme for my terminal. I do this by symlinking its configuration file and asking it (termite) to read it without closing using `killall -USR1 termite`.

I'd like my running neovims to pick up the change somehow, and set `background` to either dark or light. I've visited [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16956/1027) and [this issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6279) and other places in an effort to find out how to "refresh" neovim. And I'd like to avoid using packages like neovim-remote if possible.

`nvim --version`

```
NVIM v0.3.2-964-g7e97587da
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe
  -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -Wconversion -O2 -g -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 
  -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes 
  -std=gnu99 -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong 
  -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Wno-array-bounds 
  -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS 
  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM 
  ...

Features: +acl +iconv +jemalloc +tui 
See ":help feature-compile"
```

Comment: Must it happen automatically (nicer, but potentially hard to do) or can it be triggered manually (e.g. via a mapping/command; much easier, but requires an extra step)?

Comment: I'd like it to happen automatically. But your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I also don't mind patching the source. It would be nice to have an equivalent to vim's termresponse mechanism. But it's perhaps more useful to be able automatically call a function when neovim receives SIGUSR1.

Comment: @Bart Adding a VimL event/autocmd for SIGUSR1 is a good idea, would you mind creating a ticket: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes thanks, apparently the idea is received well: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/9564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a [new "Signal" autocmd was added](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/9564), we can automatically call a function when neovim receives SIGUSR1. Which is nice.

```sh
$ readlink -qn ~/.config/termite/config
/home/bart/.config/termite/config_dark
```

I now have this in my init.vim

```vim
" ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
" ...
au Main Signal * call Darkorlight('~/.config/termite/config')

function! Darkorlight(file) abort
  if getftype(expand(a:file)) != 'link'
    return
  endif
  if resolve(glob(expand(a:file))) =~ '_dark$'
    set background=dark
  else
    set background=light
  endif
  redraw
endfunction
```

I then watch for the symlink to change with this unit:

```
# ~/.config/systemd/user/termite.path
[Unit]
Description=Make termite reload its configuration file when it changes

[Path]
PathChanged=%h/.config/termite

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
# ~/.config/systemd/user/termite.service
[Unit]
Description=Send a signal to all termite and neovim processes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/killall -USR1 termite
ExecStart=/usr/bin/killall -USR1 nvim

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This works great. It comes in handy as a toggle switch (i.e. for a toolbar):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
conf=~/.config/termite/config
if [[ `readlink $conf 2>/dev/null` =~ light ]]; then
  ln -sf "${conf}_dark" "$conf"
else
  ln -sf "${conf}_light" "$conf"
fi
```

Thanks to Justin M. Keyes for encouraging me to ask for a scriptable Signal feature on Github, and to Marco Hinz for implementing it so quickly!